What is the limit of self-answering?
I'm relatively new to SE and claim no experience on this issue, but this question seems beyond the boundaries of reasonable self-answering. The user behind it, imz, asked two others (here and here) of the same sort. His/her answers are reasonable and do not seem to be spam, but many of them could be combined. (He/she answers one of the questions 6 times)
To me personally, it seems like rep-whoring, but being new, I have no idea if my opinions would be those of the SE community. And so I ask you, is this acceptable? How much self-answering do we want to tolerate on Bitcoin-SE?

downvoted him a few times + commented. This is clearly too much self-answering.

I don't care earning many points for the answer. I wanted to save other people's effort when they will be in need of the same services I have been looking for. Can I do something that I won't earn points, so that people won't be worried by my answers?

@imz - self-answering is ok, and even good. The problem is with the amount of different answers you posted to your own questions. People usually post just one answer, and especially to one's own question. This is just a question of measure ... we do appreciate the effort.

@imz I assure you my intent was not malevolent. Answering one question six times just seemed rather extreme. Could you explain why you did that?

Different answers are there at StackExchange, so that the participants of StackExchange can assess the different variants and collectively select the better ones. I don't have the knowledge and experience with bitcoin to write a good review as an answer to my question, but I can put the answers I was able to find for the assessment by the community. The community can add more info and promote the better answers, so that we have good answers ready for this question.

@imz Sorry I did not make my question clear. I object not to your answers, but to the separation of them. There is no reason I can discern for separating what could have been one answer into six. This is not a review site; we are not here to compare domain name providers. Source

@BinaryMage: As to the domain name registration questions, I posted a single answer with a list of the services I had found. As to the quicker spending question, there I posted several answers because of the stated reason: I can't write a good review in one answer, but I hope that among the answers, the better answers will be selected and improved by the community.

@imz Thanks for consolidating your answers from 6 to 3. That's certainly an improvement. My point is that product or website comparisons are actively discouraged on SE, as stated in my previous link. The community doesn't want to vote on which website would be best for your purpose; they want to show you what you need to look for. (again, see the source, it phrases it much better than I can) If I'm not being clear, I apologize, and in any case, I'm not going to push the issue any more. My point has been made.

I meant not just a comparison between similar services, but between the different available ways to achieve the goal: will the account hold bitcoins, or they will be exchanged at the deposit moment. So, some consolidation was reasonable: either by whether the account is in bitcoins or by what you get from the service (a physical card, or a digital card, or a transfer to another payment system).

@imz Looks like your edits made that clearer. Thanks!

Personally, the main problem I see with the linked question's answers is that they try to work too much like reviews. If the person would combine all of those answers into one, there would be no problem.

Well, there is actually a badge explicitly for self-answering questions so there's nothing inherently wrong with it, but you're right to feel like there should be a limit. Unfortunately I don't have any hard-and-fast answers about "how much is too much." Beyond a certain point it almost certainly is "rep-whoring" as you called it, but the mission here is to make the internet a better place by cataloging accurate answers to good questions - as long as those criteria are met I really couldn't care less whether some "rep-whoring" goes on in the process... Of course there are limits to everything, but for this thing I've yet to run across someone breaching that limit.
